# error sh: 0: not found while converting bash function to sh

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

The function below was originally a bash function. I need it to run in busybox 1.22 `ash` shell.

```
dockerip() {
  if (( $# != 1 ))
  then
    for d in $(docker ps -q)
    do
      name=$(docker inspect -f {{.Name}} $d)
      ip=$(docker inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} $d)
      printf "%-15s | %15s\n" $name $ip
    done
  fi
}
```

When the code above is loaded with `source` and run as `dockerip` the busybox shell outputs: `sh: 0: not found`. Not a very helpful error so my question is what does the error mean and what part(s) of the function above aren't busybox 1.22 compatible?

Comment: Most likely, the `(( $# != 1 ))` notation is trying to run the value from `$#` (plausibly 0) as a command in a double sub-shell.  Use `if [ "$#" != 1 ]` instead?  It isn't Bash-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This arithmetic expression `(( $# != 1 ))` is bash syntax. In ash, it's launching 2 nested subshells, then executing the program "$#" with arguments "!=" and "1".

Use this instead

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
```